# Missing right parantheses in oracle SQL

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

The main aim of the stored procedure of the below mentioned code is to get results from a timestamp duration of FRM_PKUP_DTT  column . The select statement if executed separately by passing the time duration , runs properly and retrieves results. I tried converting the last where statement to accept two input timstamp parameters, but when i tried executing it, I always end up in error saying missing right parentheses. I tried changing the code as much as i can and end up in different errors. Can anyone explain me what im doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

I"ll be passing values like this when i call SP '04/06/2020 00:00:00'

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TMS_Retrieve_Data(STARDATE IN  Date,ENDATE IN  DATE) 
AS
 STARTDATE   DATE:=stardate;
 ENDDATE   DATE:=endate; 


BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
INSERT INTO TMS_STG(SHPM_NUM, HOLD_YN, SHPM_STATUS, LEG_NUM, SHPM_ORIGIN, SHPM_ORIGIN_NAME, SHPM_ORIGIN_CITY, SHPM_ORIGIN_PROV, SHPM_DEST, SHPM_DEST_NAME, SHPM_DEST_CITY, SHPM_DEST_PROV, LEG_DEST, EARLY_PICKUP, LATE_PICKUP, LATE_DEL, APP_DT, PO_RECEIPT, CUST_ID, CUST_NM, CUST_EXTL_CD2, CDTY_CD, SHPM_WGT, SHPM_CUBE, SHPM_PCE, SHPM_PALLLET, MV_TYPE, MV_ID, TRIP_ID, LOAD_ID, LOAD_CREATE_DT, LOAD_START_DT, LOAD_END_DT, CARRIER_CD, SRVC_CD, LOAD_DEST, LOAD_STATUS, RATG_VLID_YN, LOAD_TRAILER_NUM, SHPM_CREATE_DT, SHPM_TRACK_NUM, SHPM_TYPE_CD, SHPM_TYPE, INCO_TERMS_CD, RVNU_TRPT_ODR_YN, PLAN_ID, PLAN_DESC, BUYER, DMCL_CD, FRST_SHPG_LOC_CD, PKUP_CONFIRM )
SELECT DISTINCT 
A.SHPM_NUM,
A.HOLD_YN,
BA_XACT_TYPES_XACT_TYPE_DESC(311, A.DISPLAY_STATUS) AS SHPM_STATUS, 
C.SEQ_NUM AS LEG_NUM, 
A.FRM_SHPG_LOC_CD AS SHPM_ORIGIN,
A.FRM_NAME AS SHPM_ORIGIN_NAME,
A.FRM_CTY_NAME AS SHPM_ORIGIN_CITY,
A.FRM_STA_CD AS SHPM_ORIGIN_PROV,
A.TO_SHPG_LOC_CD AS SHPM_DEST,
A.TO_NAME AS SHPM_DEST_NAME,
A.TO_CTY_NAME AS SHPM_DEST_CITY,
A.TO_STA_CD AS SHPM_DEST_PROV,
C.TO_SHPG_LOC_CD AS LEG_DEST, 
A.FRM_PKUP_DTT AS EARLY_PICKUP,
A.TO_PKUP_DTT AS LATE_PICKUP,
A.TO_DLVY_DTT AS LATE_DEL,
NVL(BA_TMEXTRA.TO_TIMESTAMP_SAFE(APPT.RFRC_NUM,''YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS''), BA_TMEXTRA.TO_TIMESTAMP_SAFE(APPT.RFRC_NUM,''YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'')) AS APP_DT,
BA_TMEXTRA.TO_TIMESTAMP_SAFE(POREC.RFRC_NUM,''YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'') AS PO_RECEIPT,
A.CUST_CD AS CUST_ID, 
B.CUST_NAME AS CUST_NM,
B.EXTL_CD2 CUST_EXTL_CD2,
A.CDTY_CD AS CDTY_CD,
NVL(BA_TMEXTRA.TO_NUMBER_safe(ACTUAL_WEIGHT.RFRC_NUM), A.SCLD_WGT) AS SHPM_WGT,
A.BS_VOL AS SHPM_CUBE,
A.TOT_PCE AS SHPM_PCE,
A.LDN_LEN AS SHPM_PALLLET,
(CASE WHEN (C.TRIP_ID IS NOT NULL AND C.LD_LEG_ID IS NOT NULL) THEN  ''TRIP''
WHEN (C.TRIP_ID IS NULL AND C.LD_LEG_ID IS NOT NULL) THEN  ''LOAD''
ELSE NULL END) AS MV_TYPE, 
DECODE(C.TRIP_ID, NULL, C.LD_LEG_ID, C.TRIP_ID) AS MV_ID, 
C.TRIP_ID AS TRIP_ID,
C.LD_LEG_ID AS LOAD_ID,
D.CRTD_DTT AS LOAD_CREATE_DT,
D.STRD_DTT AS LOAD_START_DT,
D.END_DTT AS LOAD_END_DT,
D.CARR_CD AS CARRIER_CD, 
D.SRVC_CD AS SRVC_CD,
D.LAST_SHPG_LOC_CD AS LOAD_DEST, 
(SELECT VAL_DESC FROM JDATM_PROD.DOM_VAL_T WHERE TAB_ID=361 AND VAL_ENU = D.CUR_OPTLSTAT_ID) AS LOAD_STATUS, 
A.RATG_VLID_YN,
D.TRLR_NUM AS LOAD_TRAILER_NUM,
A.CRTD_DTT AS SHPM_CREATE_DT,
A.SHPM_DESC AS SHPM_TRACK_NUM,
A.TO_ENT_TYP_CD AS SHPM_TYPE_CD,
SHPM_TYPE.TO_TYP_DESC AS SHPM_TYPE,
INCO.RFRC_NUM AS INCO_TERMS_CD,
A.RVNU_TRPT_ODR_YN,
A.PLAN_ID,
PLAN.PLAN_DESC,
BUYER.RFRC_NUM AS BUYER, 
D.DMCL_CD AS DMCL_CD,
D.FRST_SHPG_LOC_CD AS FRST_SHPG_LOC_CD,
A.RFRC_NUM7 AS PKUP_CONFIRM FROM 
JDATM_PROD.SHPM_T A,
JDATM_PROD.CUST_T B, 
JDATM_PROD.LD_LEG_DETL_T C, 
JDATM_PROD.LD_LEG_T D,
(
  SELECT SH.SHPM_ID,
    SH.SHPM_NUM,
    CASE
      WHEN SF.EXTL_CD2 = ''VENDOR-Z006''
      AND ST.EXTL_CD2 LIKE ''D%''
      THEN ''Inbound'' 
      WHEN SF.EXTL_CD2 = ''CUSTOMER-97''
      AND ST.EXTL_CD2  = ''CUSTOMER-97''
      THEN ''Inbound'' 
      WHEN SF.EXTL_CD2 LIKE ''V%''
      AND ST.EXTL_CD2 LIKE ''D%''
      THEN ''Inbound'' 
      WHEN SF.EXTL_CD2 LIKE ''V%''
      AND ST.EXTL_CD2 LIKE ''C%''
      THEN ''Inbound'' 
      WHEN SF.EXTL_CD2 LIKE ''V%''
      AND ST.EXTL_CD2 LIKE ''S%''
      THEN ''Inbound'' 
      WHEN SF.EXTL_CD2 LIKE ''S%''
      AND ST.EXTL_CD2 LIKE ''D%''
      THEN ''Inbound'' 
      WHEN SF.EXTL_CD2 LIKE ''V%''
      AND ST.EXTL_CD2 LIKE ''V%''
      THEN ''Inbound'' 
      ELSE ''Outbound''
    END AS ORIENTATION
  FROM JDATM_PROD.SHPM_T SH, JDATM_PROD.SHPG_LOC_T SF,  JDATM_PROD.SHPG_LOC_T ST
  WHERE SH.FRM_SHPG_LOC_CD = SF.SHPG_LOC_CD 
  AND SH.FRM_SHIP_LOC_ENU = SF.SHPG_LOC_TYP_ENU 
  AND SH.TO_SHPG_LOC_CD = ST.SHPG_LOC_CD 
  AND SH.TO_SHIP_LOC_ENU = ST.SHPG_LOC_TYP_ENU 
) DIR,  
JDATM_PROD.RFRC_NUM_T BUYER,
JDATM_PROD.DOM_VAL_T BUYER_TYPE,
JDATM_PROD.RFRC_NUM_T APPT,
JDATM_PROD.DOM_VAL_T APPT_TYPE,
JDATM_PROD.RFRC_NUM_T POREC,
JDATM_PROD.DOM_VAL_T POREC_TYPE,
JDATM_PROD.RFRC_NUM_T ACTUAL_WEIGHT, 
JDATM_PROD.DOM_VAL_T ACTUAL_WEIGHT_TYPE,
JDATM_PROD.PLAN_T  PLAN,
JDATM_PROD.TO_ENT_TYP_T SHPM_TYPE,
(
  SELECT
    T1.RFRC_NUM_TYP,
    T1.RFRC_NUM,
    T1.RFRC_NUM_QLFR_ID,
    T1.LD_LEG_ID,
    T1.SHPM_ID,
    T2.VAL_CD, 
    T2.VAL_DESC
  FROM JDATM_PROD.RFRC_NUM_T T1 INNER JOIN JDATM_PROD.DOM_VAL_T T2 ON T1.RFRC_NUM_TYP = T2.VAL_ENU
  WHERE
    T1.RFRC_NUM_TYP = 1007 AND T2.VAL_CD = ''INCO''
) INCO WHERE 1=1
AND A.SHPM_ID = C.SHPM_ID (+)
AND D.LD_LEG_ID (+) = C.LD_LEG_ID 
AND A.CUST_CD = B.CUST_CD
AND DIR.SHPM_ID = A.SHPM_ID
AND DIR.ORIENTATION = ''Inbound''
AND BUYER_TYPE.VAL_CD = ''BUYER''
AND BUYER_TYPE.VAL_ENU = 1004
AND BUYER.RFRC_NUM_TYP(+)=BUYER_TYPE.VAL_ENU
AND A.SHPM_ID = BUYER.SHPM_ID (+)
AND APPT_TYPE.VAL_CD = ''APPT''
AND APPT.RFRC_NUM_TYP(+)=APPT_TYPE.VAL_ENU
AND A.SHPM_ID = APPT.SHPM_ID (+)
AND POREC_TYPE.VAL_CD = ''PORECEIPT''
AND POREC.RFRC_NUM_TYP(+)=POREC_TYPE.VAL_ENU
AND A.SHPM_ID = POREC.SHPM_ID (+)
AND ACTUAL_WEIGHT.SHPM_ID(+)=A.SHPM_ID
AND ACTUAL_WEIGHT.RFRC_NUM_TYP(+) = ACTUAL_WEIGHT_TYPE.VAL_ENU
AND ACTUAL_WEIGHT_TYPE.VAL_CD = ''ACTUAL_WGT''
AND A.PLAN_ID = PLAN.PLAN_ID(+)
AND A.TO_ENT_TYP_CD = SHPM_TYPE.TO_ENT_TYP_CD(+)
AND A.SHPM_ID = INCO.SHPM_ID(+)
AND A.FRM_PKUP_DTT  BETWEEN '||STARTDATE||'  and            
         '||ENDDATE||' )     ';    

END;
```

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, available since SQL-92.

Comment: There is a [website](https://sql-tuning.com/convert-static-sql-to-dynamic-sql/) that converts static sql to dynamic sql.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need execute immediate, nor the local variable assignments.  Try this (I removed most of the sql to focus only on the changed parts):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TMS_Retrieve_Data(P_STARDATE IN  Date,P_ENDATE IN  DATE) 
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TMS_STG ...
  SELECT DISTINCT...
  WHERE ...
  AND A.FRM_PKUP_DTT  BETWEEN P_STARTDATE and P_ENDDATE;
END;
```

I like to prefix the parameters with P_ to make it easier to see in the query that it is a parameter, not possibly a table columns.  Also use proper ANSI join syntax instead of (+).

Comment: ```create or replace PROCEDURE TMS(P_STARTDATE IN  Date,P_ENDDATE IN  DATE) 
AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
A.SHPM_ID
FROM 
JDATM_PROD.SHPM_T A
where A.FRM_PKUP_DTT BETWEEN P_STARTDATE and P_ENDDATE;

END;
```

I cut short the code like you said  and tried running it. It says PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: That is a different statement.  Your original code had a INSERT.. SELECT.  I would suggest reading some Oracle tutorials before posting more questions.